# Why does NN training loss flatten?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

I implemented a deep learning neural network from scratch without using any python frameworks like tensorflow or keras.

The problem is no matter what i change in my code like adjusting learning rate or changing layers or changing no. of nodes or changing activation functions from sigmoid to relu to leaky relu, i end up with a training loss that starts with 6.98 but always converges to 3.24...

**Why is that?**

Please review my forward and back prop algorithms.Maybe there's something wrong in that which i couldn't identify.

My hidden layers use leaky relu and final layer uses sigmoid activation.
Im trying to classify the mnist handwritten digits.

code:

#FORWARDPROPAGATION

```
for i in range(layers-1):
    
    cache["a"+str(i+1)]=lrelu((np.dot(param["w"+str(i+1)],cache["a"+str(i)]))+param["b"+str(i+1)])


cache["a"+str(layers)]=sigmoid((np.dot(param["w"+str(layers)],cache["a"+str(layers-1)]))+param["b"+str(layers)])

yn=cache["a"+str(layers)]
m=X.shape[1]
cost=-np.sum((y*np.log(yn)+(1-y)*np.log(1-yn)))/m

if j%10==0:
    print(cost)
    costs.append(cost)
```

#BACKPROPAGATION

```
grad={"dz"+str(layers):yn-y}


for i in range(layers):
    grad["dw"+str(layers-i)]=np.dot(grad["dz"+str(layers-i)],cache["a"+str(layers-i-1)].T)/m
    

    grad["db"+str(layers-i)]=np.sum(grad["dz"+str(layers-i)],1,keepdims=True)/m
    
    if i<layers-1:
        grad["dz"+str(layers-i-1)]=np.dot(param["w"+str(layers-i)].T,grad["dz"+str(layers-i)])*lreluDer(cache["a"+str(layers-i-1)])

for i in range(layers):
    param["w"+str(i+1)]=param["w"+str(i+1)] - alpha*grad["dw"+str(i+1)]
    param["b"+str(i+1)]=param["b"+str(i+1)] - alpha*grad["db"+str(i+1)]
```

Comment: are these two numbers 6.98 and 3.24 coming exactly same every time?

Comment: ya,it stays at 3.24 till around 10000 iterations and then it overshoots i guess(i get some error about division by zero).

Answer (score 0):

The implementation seems okay. While you could converge to the same value with different models/learning rate/hyper parameters, what's frightening is having the same starting value everytime, 6.98 in your case.

I suspect it has to do with your initialisation. If you're setting all your weights initially to zero, you're not gonna break symmetry. That is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638646/what-does-it-mean-to-break-symmetry-in-the-context-of-neural-network-programm) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/danger-of-setting-all-initial-weights-to-zero-in-backpropagation) in adequate detail.